# URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier without iCloud enabled?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, icloud

I have an app which I want to work the same every time, regardless of whether or not iCloud is enabled. Thus, I want to store my core data persistent store in the same place with iCloud enabled as I would without it enabled.

If iCloud is enabled, calling

```
NSURL *iCloudURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier];
```

gives the result:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/12345~com~andrew~icloudid/
```

Calling this without iCloud enabled returns nil. I'd like to be able to access it when iCloud isn't enabled, to still use my core data store from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this same setup on the *device* rather than the simulator.

You will discover that the ubiquity container URL will be the same regardless of the user setting.